# Rebus #15 is a bilingual one

Tags: rebus

This is the French spelling of an English word.

[image]

Comment: I speak French. Easy peasy! All I did way the words out loud. :P Also, skin-head-water means nothing unless you're referring to skin head wigs?

Comment: Tu me fais rire, toi!

Comment: Est ce que c'est correct?

Comment: @YoutRied:  Bien sur!  I got a good chuckle out of your first, spot on, comment. :)

Comment: Not sure how it's a rebus, though? :S

Comment: I'm not even sure that it is a puzzle at all with the verbatim explanation.

Comment: @jafe:  Rebuses can be either pictorial or just words.  Take a gander at these:  fun-with-words.com/rebus_puzzles.html

Comment: @MOehm:  verbatim explanation?  Sorry, no comprendo.  In any case, it would be puzzling for anybody who doesn't know French.

Comment: "This is the French spelling of an English word" -- if that isn't verbatim, what is? (Okay, I should have written "explicit", sorry.) If you have a even only basic knowledge of how French words are pronounced, this is a write-in. You don't even have to know the meaning of those words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this

> Potato?

Because

> Peau is pronounced po, tete is pronounced tet, and eau is pronounced o.

Comment: Formidable, Yout!

Comment: Peut-être tu peux faire des plus difficicles questions... :)

Comment: Eh ben, @Yout Ried:  pour les Americains qui ne parlent pas ta langue, celui-ci est assez difficile. =D

Comment: C'est vrai, mais Beauvoir de personnes sur ce site web parle plus qu'un langue.